# string comparison on java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare two strings. Actually strings are equal in logs. but not in practice.

```
String c = calculateHash();
if (!c.equals("Xo8WBi6jzSxKDVR4drqm84yr9iU=")){
//error
}
```

other function

```
static String calculateHash() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        PackageInfo info = reactContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(reactContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            s.append(Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
        Log.e("MKHash1",s.toString());
        return s.toString();
    }
```

E/MKHash1: Xo8WBi6jzSxKDVR4drqm84yr9iU=

Comment: Have you tried using `if("Xo8WBi6jzSxKDVR4drqm84yr9iU=" != c)`

Comment: yes error again

Comment: What error? Please post the `Logcat` logs in the question...

Comment: no error... it drops into if statement...strings must be equal

Comment: Try using `String.trim();`

Comment: String c="Xo8WBi6jzSxKDVR4drqm84yr9iU=";
                    if(c!="Xo8WBi6jzSxKDVR4drqm84yr9iU="){
                        Log.e("Hello world!","");
                    } this has no issues,, but calling with function has error in equality

Comment: with trim() still strings not same

Comment: it says length is 29,, but string shows 28 in logcat, how to find out

Comment: i put = at the end of the string and its done,,,

Comment: Using `!=` is _definitely_ wrong.  Using `.equals`, as in the original post, is correct.

Comment: I think @Vishnu is right, i tried the same code with trim and it gives that they are the same

Comment: Try `s.toString().trim().equals("Xo8WBi6jzSxKDVR4drqm84yr9iU=")`

Comment: function outputs Xo8WBi6jzSxKDVR4drqm84yr9iU==, which is 1 = more.